# Navigation Menu is empty

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I'm currently testing syncfusion's navigation drawer, I am following the tutorial here https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfnavigationdrawer/getting-started?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp When the navigation is loaded, it's empty. May I ask whwere am I going wrong?

I've copied the xaml code to my xaml page and the c# behind. It compiles fine and displayed below.

[image]
[image]

Code from tutorial

MainPage.xaml

```
<navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer x:Name="navigationDrawer" DrawerWidth ="200" DrawerHeaderHeight="160">
    <navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerContentView>
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout HeightRequest="40">
                            <Label Margin="10,7,0,0" Text="TEST" FontSize="16"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerContentView>
</navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()

{
    InitializeComponent();
    navigationDrawer.DrawerWidth = 200;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("Home");
    list.Add("Profile");
    list.Add("Inbox");
    list.Add("Out box");
    list.Add("Sent");
    list.Add("Draft");
    listView.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see

Comment: @Jason added the code

Comment: I'd suggest getting rid of all that complex layout and start with something as simple as possible, like a single Label.  Get that to work first, then iteratively add in more complex layout elements.

Comment: @Jason I've simplified it, the navigation still appears blank.

Comment: I tested your code and it works well on my side. I use the latest version of `Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfNavigationDrawer`. You can try to clean and rebuild your project to see if it works. I can give your my sample if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 16.4.0.52 with Xamarin.forms 3.5.0.129452 display empty content and crashes with Xamarin.forms 3.4.0.1029999.

The version 16.4.0.48 crashes with Xamarin.forms 3.5.0.129452.

The only combination that works for me is the 16.4.0.48 with Xamarin.forms 3.4.0.1029999.